# как сгруппировать json?

Tags: dart

нужно сгруппировать следующий json по ключу "name" и суммировать значения ключа "economy":

```
[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "economy": 30.0,
    "abp": "abp1_1"
  },
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "economy": 20.0,
    "abp": "abp1_2"
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "economy": 32.0,
    "abp": "abp2_1"
  },
  
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "economy": 31.2,
    "abp": "abp2_2"
  }
]
```

на выходе я должен получить следующее:

```
[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "economy": 40.0,
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "economy": 30.0,
        "abp": "abp1_1"
      },
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "economy": 20.0,
        "abp": "abp1_2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "economy": 63.2,
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "name2",
        "economy": 32.0,
        "abp": "abp2_1"
      },
      {
        "name": "name2",
        "economy": 31.2,
        "abp": "abp2_2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Могу на c# замутить

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/darq

Answer (score 0):

По первому запросу, выдаётся [библиотека](https://github.com/google/serialization.dart)

Документация, вязатя из библиотеки:

Импорт либо

`import "package:serialization/serialization.dart"`
или

`import "package:serialization/serialization_mirrors.dart"`
в зависимости от того, нужны ли вам зеркальные правила. Они более удобны, но вызывают увеличение размера кода в dartj2s.

Чтобы использовать трансформатор, включите в pubspec что-то вроде

```
transformers:
  - serialization :
    $include: ["lib/stuff.dart", "lib/more_stuff.dart"]
```

Затем настройте сгенерированные правила в экземпляре сериализации, а затем вызовите функцию write(). Правила сериализации будут называться так же, как имя файла модели с `_serialization_rules` добавлением к нему , так что в случае `stuff.dartstuff_serialization_rules.dart`, если он находится в том же каталоге, что и оригинал.

Обычно вы никогда не увидите эти файлы, потому что трансформатор создает его на лету, и он отправляется непосредственно в pub serve или в dart2js, никогда не записываясь на диск. Чтобы увидеть сгенерированный код, запустите pub build в режиме отладки, например , если в каталоге пакета есть программа binдля запуска чего -либо с помощью этих файлов, то

`pub build --mode=debug bin`
будет генерировать код для этого, а также регистрировать, какие файлы были сгенерированы, в виде

`Generated serialization rules in my_package|lib/stuff_serialization_rules.dart`
Кроме того, можно запустить код трансформатора вне трансформатора, что полезно для отладки или использования кода по -другому. Пример этого см. в разделе `"test/transformer/generate_standalone.dart"`.

Код каталога bin будет выглядеть примерно так.

```
import 'package:my_package/stuff_serialization_rules.dart' as foo;
 ...
 var serialization = new Serialization();
 foo.rules.values.forEach(serialization.addRule);
 ...
 sendToClient(serialization.write(somePerson));
а на клиенте сделайте что-нибудь вроде

 p = readFromServer(personId).then((data) => serialization.read(data));
```

В качестве альтернативы, если вы используете зеркальные правила, просто сообщите сериализации, какие классы могут быть сериализованы.

```
var serialization = new Serialization()
  ..addRuleFor(Person);
  ..addRuleFor(Address);
serialization.write(address);
```

Для получения более конкретных примеров см. testКаталог, и особенно для примеров трансформатора может быть полезно посмотреть pubspec.yamlна этот пакет и test/transformer каталог.

---

Если вдруг, библиотека перестанет поддерживаться, то будущие поситители смогут найти второй вариант решения данной проблемы [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681565/object-de-serialization-using-dart)

Comment: Ваш ответ никак не относиться к вопросу...

Comment: Мой ответ рассказывает как сериализировать/десериализировать json структуры, если вам нужен готовый код - идите на фриланс

Comment: Где связь между сгруппировать json и сериализировать/десериализировать json?

Comment: ам, если ты сможешь получить опр.поля из json, то думаю не составит трудности их рассортировать и сериализовать